# Getting result 1 more, divisor counting Program - C

Tags: c

> Write a program which reads in an integer k, and prints out the number of positive integers between 1 and 100000 (inclusive) which have exactly k divisors.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main(void){
    int k=0, N=0, i=0, r=0, n_divisors=0, result=0;
    printf("Enter the number of divisors: ");

/*scanning in an integer value*/
    scanf(" %d",&k);
/*loop to count the no. of divisors in an integer from 1 to 100000*/ 
    for(N=1; N<=100000; N++){
            n_divisors=0;
/*loop for incrementing the no. divisors in an integer by 2 */
      for(i=1; i<sqrt(N); i++ ){
/*Testing if i is a divisor of the integer.*/
                r=(N%i);
                if( r==0)
                    n_divisors+=2;
      }
/* If the no. of divisors is equal to k, then increment result*/
                if(n_divisors==k)
                    result++;
/* else reset the value of no. of divisors to 0*/
    }
/* printing the value for no. of integers form 1 to 100000 with K no. of divisors*/
        printf("There are %d numbers between 1 and 100000 inclusive which have exactly  \n",result  );
        printf("%d divisors.",k);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Very strange commenting in C (`> comment//`). My compiler don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more serious as you think - you may obtain strange results, not only increased by 1. (See: You count number of divisors by adding `2`, *as all numbers could have only **even** numbers of divisors*.)

The problem is in this statement:

```
        for(i=1; i<sqrt(N); i++ ){
```

particularly in the expression

```
        i<sqrt(N)
```

in it which *excludes* `sqrt(N)` from possible divisors.

But for numbers which *are* 2nd power of integers (as `1`, `4`, `9`, `16`, ...) the `sqrt(N)` ***is*** their divisor.

So insert into your code something as

```
        if (i * i == N)
            n_divisors++;
```

so touched part of your code will then look as (I added correct indentations)

```
// loop to count the no. of divisors in an integer from 1 to 100000
for(N=1; N<=100000; N++){
    n_divisors=0;
    // loop for incrementing the no. divisors in an integer by 2
    for(i=1; i<sqrt(N); i++ ){
        // Testing if i is a divisor of the integer.
        r=(N%i);
        if( r==0)
            n_divisors+=2;
    }
    if (i * i == N)
        n_divisors++;
    //  If the no. of divisors is equal to k, then increment result//
    if(n_divisors==k)
        result++;
    // else reset the value of no. of divisors to 0//
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i had a feeling it was serious for a range of values but wasn't sure what they where.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me once the comments are removed as they're causing some issues

**cleaned up code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
int k=0, i=0, n_divisors=0, result=0;
double N=0, r=0;
printf("Enter the number of divisors: ");

scanf(" %d",&k);
for(N=1; N<=100000; N++){
    n_divisors=0;
  for(i=1; i<sqrt(N); i++ ){
        r=fmod(N, i);
        if( r==0)
            n_divisors+=2;
 }
            if(n_divisors==k)
            result++;
}
printf("There are %d numbers between 1 and 100000 inclusive which have exactly\n",result);
printf("%d divisors.",k);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry about the commenting, the correct answer should be result=10728.

Comment: @Omar given what input exactly?

Comment: when k=16, result=10728 , for the range 1 to 100000